# How to Convert Types, or pass values between types?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes that hold the same data, but I can't pass the values between the two due to `Type` confilcts.

These are the two classes,

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

    public Employee(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        FirstName = first;
        SecondName = second;
    }
}

public class EmployeeList
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

    public EmployeeList(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        FirstName = first;
        SecondName = second;
    }
}
```

I then use properties to store the data via LINQ queries,

```
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Staff { get; set; } =
   new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

public ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> StaffAll { get; set; } =
   new ObservableCollection<EmployeeList>();
```

Then I pass the values into a property for each,

```
private Employee _selectedEmployee;

public Employee SelectedEmployee
{
    get { return _selectedEmployee; }
    set
    {
        _selectedEmployee = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private EmployeeList _selectedEmployeeAll;

public EmployeeList SelectedEmployeeAll
{
    get { return _selectedEmployeeAll; }
    set
    {
        _selectedEmployeeAll = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Eg,

```
SelectedEmployee = Staff.First();
SelectedEmployeeAll = StaffAll.First();
```

And what I want to do is pass the values from one class to the other, like something like this,

```
SelectedEmployee = SelectedEmployeeAll;
```

But of coarse , due to `type` conflicts I can't pass the data from one to the other. How do I go about passing the data from one type to the other?

Comment: Why do you have two classes that are the same? Seems like bad design to me.

Comment: Like this: `SelectedEmployee = new Employee(SelectedEmployeeAll.Key, SelectedEmployeeAll.FirstName, SelectedEmployeeAll.SecondName);`

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I need two sets of data. I tried doing this with just one set of data, but it did not work.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. What "did not work"?

Comment: I still don't understand. You can use two collections of a single type, two properties of the same type, why have two types that are the same?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I don't know how to have both properties update when a value is changed. I am using WPF and binding each property to a control.

Comment: Type name `EmployeeList` is not a list at all. Phew!

Comment: @RBT, are we fussing over naming conventions now?

Comment: Absolutely not. But it certainly makes it very difficult to understand the post.

Comment: Actually @RBT does have a valid point...

Comment: @RBT, I know I have to work on them, but I am redoing all my old code to streamline it and I just posted as it was when I first made it.

Comment: I think Roma's answer should do the trick for you then.

Comment: Why create two classes to store the same information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create `Employee` from `EmployeeList`:

```
SelectedEmployee = new Employee(SelectedEmployeeAll.Key, SelectedEmployeeAll.FirstName, SelectedEmployeeAll.SecondName);
```

But you should try to use only one type because it is not good design to have two identical types.

If you want to use it in multiple apps consider creating shared `Class Library`.

Comment: This doesn't compile - `CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'key' of 'Employee.Employee(int, string, string)'`

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks, it was my mistake, I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand for what do you use one class with different names. You can do this:

```
public class EmployeeList:Employee
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

    public EmployeeList(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        FirstName = first;
        SecondName = second;
    }
}
```

But right way, I think, is to use only one class.

Comment: Exactly same set of properties repeated in base and the inherited class? I think something isn't right here. I believe C# compiler will give you a warning to use `new` keyword if hiding was intended. You should not have these properties at all in the derived class.

Comment: I agree - it's not a correct decision. but C# compiler didn't give a warning,- and i post it as alternative way.